# How to compare missing data in two netcdf files using python?

Tags: python, netcdf

I have two netcdf files: file1 (cru pre) and file2 (chirps precip). Both files have been remapped to the same grid, contain monthly data and cover the same time period (1981-2017).

How do I use python to loop through the files and achieve the following logic:
for each data point in file1
if the value is not missing and the corresponding file2 value is not missing
then keep the file1 value and the file2 value
else treat as missing

I basically want to get an output_file1 which only contains file1 data for points where file2 is not missing and an output_file2 which only contains file2 data for points where file1 is not missing. In both files I have set missing_values to 999.

I am new to python and working with NetCDF files and would appreciate any guidance.

Comment: You can try `xarrary` https://github.com/pydata/xarray to have a good start:)

Comment: Thank you, I did get them into xarrays but still had some trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this with a few lines using my nctoolkit packages (https://nctoolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

To do the first file, try the following.

```
import nctoolkit as nc
# read in the data
ds1 = nc.open_data("file1.nc")
ds2 = nc.open_data("file2.nc")

# create a mask, where 1 is non-missing data, missing is missing
# change var to whatever the variable is named
ds2.assign(mask = lambda x: x.var == x.var, drop = True)
# multiply the first file by the masked file
ds1.multiply(ds2)
# save the output file
ds1.to_nc("file1_fixed.nc)
```

This will do the masking at each time step.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try this method.

Comment: nctoolkit is very useful - thanks! I wanted to ask, after doing a series of selections (years and area) and calculating the tmean of a dataset, how I could plot it using matplotlib? These are the commands I performed and I need to repeat these for different sub-regions and tile the plots together and would feel more comfortable doing that with matplotlib:                
ds1.select(variables = "pre")
ds1.select(years = range(1981, 2018))
ds1.crop(lon = [20, 27], lat = [-35, -33.5])
ds1.spatial_mean()
ds1.tmean("month")

Comment: There is an autoplot feature. Just do `ds.plot()`. If you wanted to use matplotlib, you could export to xarray using `ds_xr = ds1.to_xarray()`

Comment: thank you! I did use ds.plot() but it was not quite what I am looking for. I will try export to xarray.